# Midnight Commander displays 'Unselect' dialog when I press F4 to edit a file

Tags: mc

When I press F4 in Midnight Commander, I expect it to edit a file. It displays the 'Unselect' dialog instead. What could have caused it and how can I fix it?

This may or may not be caused by [my attempts to change the editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123330/how-to-set-environment-variables) to `nano`

Comment: Post the output of `echo $EDITOR` from inside `mc` while it is running.

Comment: `/usr/bin/nano`

Comment: Pretty odd.  Does this happen when you try it from an actual VT (i.e., a non-GUI console accessed via alt-ctrl-F1-6)?

Comment: Which version of `mc` is it and what terminal do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, SSH'd into a mostly fresh CentOS 7 box from another CentOS 7 box.  Weird, because I hit CentOS boxes all the time and use mc constantly and I've not seen this one before.

In any case, it turned out to be the TERM settings.  My client had `TERM=xterm-256color`, the server had `TERM=linux`.  Not sure if the client was relaying it, but either way changing the server to TERM=xterm fixed the problem.  Directly into the editor on hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Hope this helps the next person that stumbles on it.